# How do I get the current date time on a Post-build action in a Delphi build

Tags: delphi, msbuild, delphi-2010

I'm trying to save the compilation time of a project on a text file every time a project is compiled/built, so I've tried to put the following command in the project's options Post-Build Action:

```
echo %date% %time% > "$(PROJECTDIR)\$(PROJECTNAME).txt"
```

But Cmd-style %date% variables won't work. I've also tried the following:

- MSBuild-style $(date)
- MSBuild 4-style $([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString(`yyyy.MMdd`))
- Calling cmd:

  ```
  cmd.exe /C echo %date% %time% > "$(PROJECTDIR)\$(PROJECTNAME).txt"
  ```

But none of those options work. I know there are Community Tasks that enable this sort of thing but I'm trying to avoid the need to install them in every developer's PC.

Comment: Another way to do this with another batch script https://stackoverflow.com/a/49129365/469898

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pull the date/time from the project you just built and send it to a text file, with the date and time on a single line.  Add this to the post-build commands:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims= " %%i in ('dir "$(OUTPUTDIR)$(OUTPUTFILENAME)" ^| find "$(OUTPUTFILENAME)"') do echo %%i %%j %%k > "$(PROJECTDIR)$(PROJECTNAME).txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `date` and `time` commands to output the time and date. Pass the `/t` switch to tell these commands just to output the current value.

```
C:\>date /t
25/09/2013

C:\>time /t
15:06
```

So, to put these values into a file do this:

```
date /t > "$(PROJECTDIR)\$(PROJECTNAME).txt"
time /t >> "$(PROJECTDIR)\$(PROJECTNAME).txt"
```

Perhaps writing this information to a file isn't the best solution to your problem. The compiler will write the build date into the output file. TOndrej's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437300/how-can-i-automate-getting-the-date-of-build-into-a-constant-visible-to-my-code) shows how to retrieve it:

Comment: It would be better if the time were on the same line as the date, but I can work with that